# Audio .pause() method doesn't work unless in global scope

Tags: javascript

I'm making a simple Rock-Paper-Scissors game. With every outcome, there should be an equivalent sound played(that's been done), not only that but if the prior sound is still playing, then it should stop before the current one starts, and therein lies my problem: I can only make that work(stop prior sounds) if I move the whatever variable or object that holds "new Audio"(in this case, playSound) to global scope.

I've tried everything I could think of, after hours fiddling with variables, functions, etc, I eventually settled down with an object(playSound). I don't know what else to do or why it's behaving this way, and I really want to solve this without resorting to global scope.

```
const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  const playSound = {
    winSound: new Audio("sound/kids-shouting-yay-sound-effect.mp3"),
    loseSound: new Audio("sound/aww-sound-effect.mp3"),
    tieSound: new Audio("sound/roblox-death-sound.mp3"),

    stopSound() {
      this.winSound.pause();
      this.winSound.currentTime = 0;
      this.loseSound.pause();
      this.loseSound.currentTime = 0;
      this.tieSound.pause();
      this.tieSound.currentTime = 0;
    },

    playerWin() {
      this.stopSound();
      this.winSound.play();
      return `Player wins! :D`;
    },

    playerLose() {
      this.stopSound();
      this.loseSound.play();
      return `Computer wins! :(`;
    },

    playerTie() {
      this.stopSound();
      this.tieSound.play();
      return `It's a tie! :/`;
    }
  };

  if ((userChoice === computerChoice)) {
    return playSound.playerTie()
  } else if ((userChoice === 'rock')) {
      if ((computerChoice === 'paper')) {
        return playSound.playerLose();
      } else {
        return playSound.playerWin();
      }
  } else if ((userChoice === 'paper')) {
        if ((computerChoice === 'scissors')) {
        return playSound.playerLose();
      } else {
        return playSound.playerWin();
      }
  } else if ((userChoice === 'scissors')) {
      if ((computerChoice === 'rock')) {
        return playSound.playerLose();
      } else {
        return playSound.playerWin();
      }
  }
};
```

For more info on code, here's the github's repo:
https://github.com/RenanMDP/rock-paper-scissors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the prior sound is still playing, then it should stop before the current one starts

Audio can be a tricky thing, here are some things to consider and suggestions:

1. Audio is an async operation, therefore, events are typically a better way to manage them
2. Chrome returns audio methods such as `play` as a Promise, therefore a `stop` cannot be done synchronously
3. If you use only one `Audio` element, you can effectively play just one sound at a time (`stopSound` is not needed)
4. `const` are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), therefore are still put in the global scope, use an [iife](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) if you want to keep the global scope clean

```js
(function(){ // iife

// hand choice functions
const rock = document.querySelector("#rock");
rock.onclick = function() {
  let userInput;
  userInput = rock.getAttribute("id");

  const userChoice = userInput;
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

  document.querySelector("#compChoice").textContent = `Computer picked: ${computerChoice}`;
  document.querySelector("#outcome").textContent = `${determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice)}`;
}

const paper = document.querySelector("#paper");
paper.onclick = function() {
  let userInput;
  userInput = paper.getAttribute("id");

  const userChoice = userInput;
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

  document.querySelector("#compChoice").textContent = `Computer picked: ${computerChoice}`;
  document.querySelector("#outcome").textContent = `${determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice)}`;
}

const scissors = document.querySelector("#scissors");
scissors.onclick = function() {
  let userInput;
  userInput = scissors.getAttribute("id");

  const userChoice = userInput;
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

  document.querySelector("#compChoice").textContent = `Computer picked: ${computerChoice}`;
  document.querySelector("#outcome").textContent = `${determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice)}`;
}

// gets the computer choice
const getComputerChoice = () => {
  const compInput = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

  switch (compInput) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock';
      break;
    case 1:
      return 'paper';
      break;
    case 2:
      return 'scissors';
      break;
  }
};

// decides the outcome based on user and computer choices
const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  const playSound = {
    audio: document.querySelector("audio"),

    winSound: "https://renanmdp.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/sound/kids-shouting-yay-sound-effect.mp3",
    loseSound: "https://renanmdp.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/sound/aww-sound-effect.mp3",
    tieSound: "https://renanmdp.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/sound/roblox-death-sound.mp3",

    playWinSound() {
      this.audio.src = this.winSound;
      this.audio.play();
    },

    playLoseSound() {
      this.audio.src = this.loseSound;
      this.audio.play();
    },

    playTieSound() {
      this.audio.src = this.tieSound;
      this.audio.play();
    }
  };

  if ((userChoice === computerChoice)) {
    playSound.playTieSound();
    return `It's a tie! :/`;
  } else if ((userChoice === 'rock')) {
    if ((computerChoice === 'paper')) {
      playSound.playLoseSound();
      return `Computer wins! :(`;
    } else {
      playSound.playWinSound();
      return `Player wins! :D`;
    }
  } else if ((userChoice === 'paper')) {
    if ((computerChoice === 'scissors')) {
      playSound.playLoseSound();
      return `Computer wins! :(`;
    } else {
      playSound.playWinSound();
      return `Player wins! :D`;
    }
  } else if ((userChoice === 'scissors')) {
    if ((computerChoice === 'rock')) {
      playSound.playLoseSound();
      return `Computer wins! :(`;
    } else {
      playSound.playWinSound();
      return `Player wins! :D`;
    }
  }
};

})();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#main-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(81, 156, 156);
}

img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

#result {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  /* border: 5px solid black; */
}

#outcome {
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; */
  color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Pick your hand
</h1>
<div id="main-card">
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Rock</figcaption>
    <img id="rock" src="https://renanmdp.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/img/rps-rock.png">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Paper</figcaption>
    <img id="paper" src="https://renanmdp.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/img/rps-paper.png">
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <figcaption>Scissors</figcaption>
    <img id="scissors" src="https://renanmdp.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/img/rps-scissors.png">
  </figure>
  <div id="result">
    <h3 id="compChoice"></h3>
    <h1 id="outcome"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- add empty audio element as a single container for all audio -->
<audio preload="none"></audio>
```

Comment: I guess it circled back to having an audio element. I was hoping to solve this with the "new Audio" JS only but oh well. It seems synchronization is the issue though I don't know exactly what is going on. Anyway, thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

### Make one source of voice

like `var currSound = new Audio("...");`

And then BEFORE use currSound.play(), change currSound to the audio you want to play.

one more comment, try to avoid duplicated lines.. instead of that:

```
if ((computerChoice === 'paper')) {
    playSound.stopSound();
    playSound.playLoseSound();
    return `Computer wins! :(`;
  } else {
    playSound.stopSound();
    playSound.playWinSound();
    return `Player wins! :D`;
  }
```

Write somthing like that:

```
if ((computerChoice === 'paper')) {
    return computerWin();
  } else {
    return playerWin();
  }

function computerWin(){
 playSound.stopSound();
 playSound.playLoseSound();
 return `Computer wins! :(`;
}
```

I gave a small example

ok, you need to stop the song and then..

```
   playerWin() {
     this.currSound.pause();
     this.currSound = new Audio("sound/aww-sound-effect.mp3");
     this.currSound.play();
     return `Player wins! :D`;
   },
```

Comment: I tried your solution, created a variable before the conditional and then assigned it to whatever sound I wanted to play before calling .play() but it's still behaving the same way, it plays the sounds but it doesn't pause and reset the prior sound. I'll refactor the code as you pointed out.

Comment: I add in my answer

Comment: Didn't work, I had to create an audio channel, but thanks for helping me!